# Expressing $z\in G$ as $z=gh^2$ where $g$ is a $2$-element and $|h|$ is odd

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $z\in G$ where $G$ is a finite group, then is it always true that there exist elements $g,h\in G$ such that $z=gh^2$ where $|g|=2^k$ for  $k \in \Bbb{Z_{\ge0}}$ and $|h|$ is odd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can take either $g$ or $h$ to be identity too , so if $z$ is a  2-element or square of an odd order element then it is obvious.

Now , we assume that  $n=|z|=2^k.s=t.s$ where $s$ is odd and $t=2^k$ for some $k\in \Bbb{Z^+}$.

Now as $(s,t)=1$ there exist $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $at+sb=1$ which implies $z^1=z^{at+sb}=z^{at}.z^{sb}$ where $z^{(at)s}=1$ implies order of $z^{at}=z^{a.2^k}=(z^{2})^{a.2^{k-1}}$ divides $s$ and is thus odd and similarly $|z^{bs}|$ is a power of $2$ as $z^{bst}=1$.

Only thing remains is if $k=0$ i.e. $n$ is odd, i.e. order of $z$ is odd, then prove that "Every group element of odd order can be expressed as a power of square of itself " and we are done